# Keycloak: How to identify the user when changing his/her password with the admin REST api?

Tags: keycloak, change-password

I have a Keycloak(KC) server which is not accessible from internet. All operations (user creation, login, logout, password change) are backed by a web ui (Angular app) and backend (Spring Boot) applications.
The backend app is created as a `confidential` client and use the KC Admin REST api to create and manage users.

With that configuration, I would like to let the user to change his/her password but I am stuck! 
How to be sure that the user requesting to change the password is the same user that one POSTing the new password?

The password change flow is:

**a.** User asks to change the password by POSTing his/her email address

**b.** He/She receives an email with a link containing a token (this token can only be used once)

**c.** After clicking the link, he/she is redirected to the form to fill in the new password.

**d.** After POSTing the new password, the backend app sends it to KC.

I am stuck on the last step. I would like to protect the endpoint accepting a new password to be sure that only user in the password change flow can POST data.

My first idea was to request a temporary access token from KC using the user username and the backend app credentials, that token would contain a special role (say **ROLE_CHANGE_PASSWORD**), then send back that access token when redirecting the user to the new password form (step **c.**); so when POSTing the new password, we would also authenticate at the same time with that temporary token containing the good role to access the endpoint.

The problem is:

- How can the backend app requests an access token containing the user's username without knowing the user password? I don't want to use `offline_access` for many reasons.

Do you have a better solution to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is your angular app protected by Keycloak ? who is generating the token when user requesting for password change?

Comment: @ravthiru Yes the angular app is proptected by Keycloak, I would like the token to be generated by the backend app.

Comment: If your angular app is already protected by keycloak, why you want your app to handle passwords. you can redirect to keycloak , so user can directly change password.

Comment: user can be redirected to /auth/realms/<realm>/account  to manage his password.

Comment: @ravthiru As said above, keycloak is not accessible from internet so I can’t redirect the user.